# window.onerror only works within <script> tags?

Tags: javascript

I have a small little window.onerror script that looks like this:

```
    window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    console.log('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' + linenumber + ' for ' + url);
}
```

The problem, is that it only works if I put it on an html page within  tags like this:

```
 <script>
        window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    console.log('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' + linenumber + ' for ' + url);
}
 </script>
```

However, I'd like to put it in a separate .js file so multiple pages can use it.

Comment: Should make zero difference... Are you sure the JavaScript file is properly added to the page?

Comment: What code are you using to include the script?

Comment: Are you asking *how* to do a file-include, or asking *why* ***your*** attempt at a file-include doesn't work? Ensure that your script is being loaded and make sure your `<script src="...">` is in the exact same place as your `<script>` currently is. If you add the `window.onerror` file after the you include the file that produces the error, you might not catch it.

Comment: You mentioned that *"I'd like to put it in a separate .js file"*, does this mean that you didn't. Are you just writing this directly on the HTML page? If so then obviously you can't write JavaScript inside of HTML content. If you did place this into a another file (hopefully), then show us how you referenced it in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a different file, call this file whatever.js and include it like this:

```
<script src="path/to/whatever.js"></script>
```

to all your files you want to include the script to...

**whatever.js:**

```
   window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    console.log('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' + linenumber + ' for ' + url);
}
```